# add hours to time string to match time zone in python

Tags: python, date

I have a string that looks like this

`time = "2020-04-15 21:27"`

That's based on normal time zone +0

how can i add hours to the string so it become like this

for example let's add 5 hours to the time

the time string will become like this

`time = "2020-04-15 02:27"`

then the day should be updated
so the final result will look like this

`time = "2020-04-15 02:27"`

how can i do that ?

Edit:

i also need to change the day because 24 hours have passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear if you mean creating your own clock or just updating a string every hour.

Option one:

```
import time
While True:
    t = time.ctime(%h)
    print(t)
#the above produces a live clock only showing hours.
#you could add %s for seconds separated by commas and thd like.
```

Option 2:

```
import time
T = #whatever you want it to be
time.sleep(300)
T = the prev num bit you want to change + 5
```

Hope this helps!
Happy coding